# Laravel Livewire Calculator/Keypad, Improving speed of input to display

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

Making a calculator/keypad using Laravel and Livewire and at the point where I am able to click a number button and it shows in the display. The problem is there is a slight lag, and I am wondering if there is a better way of doing this that cuts down on the lag.

I have it set up where the Livewire "controller" has a method called append that attaches the selected number, passed through as a value, to a property called display.

In the Livewire "view" I connected the append method to the button, for example, 0 button would be wire:click="append('0')"

Livewire "controller" test.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Test extends Component
{

    public $display = "";


    public function append($foo){
        if(strlen($this->display) < 4){
            
            return $this->display = $this->display.$foo;

        }

    }

    public function clear(){
      
        $this->display = "";

    }

    public function render()
    {
        
        return view('livewire.test');
        
    }
}
```

Livewire "view" test.blade.php

```
<div>
    
    <div class="h-16 w-full border border-black  rounded-sm" >{{$display}} </div>
    <div class="w-8/12 sm:w-full grid grid-cols-3 gap-x-8 gap-y-8">

            <div> <button wire:click="clear()" class="bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-full  h-16 w-16 flex items-center justify-center"> AC</button></div>
            <div> <button wire:click="append('0')" class="bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-full  h-16 w-16 flex items-center justify-center"> 0</button></div>
            <div> <button class="bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-full  h-16 w-16 flex items-center justify-center"> S</button></div>
            <div><button wire:click="append('1')" class="bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-full  h-16 w-16 flex items-center justify-center"> 1</button></div>
            <div><button wire:click="append('2')" class="bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-full  h-16 w-16 flex items-center justify-center">2</button></div>
            <div> <button wire:click="append('3')" class="bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-full  h-16 w-16 flex items-center justify-center"> 3</button></div>
            <div> <button wire:click="append('4')" class="bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-full  h-16 w-16 flex items-center justify-center"> 4</button></div>
            <div> <button wire:click="append('5')" class="bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-full  h-16 w-16 flex items-center justify-center"> 5</button></div>
            <div> <button wire:click="append('6')" class="bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-full  h-16 w-16 flex items-center justify-center"> 6</button></div>
            <div> <button wire:click="append('7')" class="bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-full  h-16 w-16 flex items-center justify-center"> 7</button></div>
            <div> <button wire:click="append('8')" class="bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-full  h-16 w-16 flex items-center justify-center"> 8</button></div>
            <div> <button wire:click="append('9')" class="bg-transparent hover:bg-blue-500 text-blue-700 font-semibold hover:text-white py-2 px-4 border border-blue-500 hover:border-transparent rounded-full  h-16 w-16 flex items-center justify-center"> 9</button></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

How can I make input to display more instant, and not have this slight lag?

Answer (score 0):

I think I was using Livewire incorrectly and should use Javascript, in this case Alpine js. It just took me some time to arrived to the realiztion that I am using the TALL stack.